# vuecli with webextensions: Precompile & load content script

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

I am creating a web-extension with `vuejs` & `vue-cli`. I have added my content script to be processed with `vue-cli`s internal `webpack`, s.t.:

```
configureWebpack: {
    entry: {
      contentScript: "./src/contentScript/contentScript.js"
    }
```

Compilation works. I am getting out a `contentScript.js`, a webpack-bundled file. However, when I try to load this file using:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  file: "js/contentScript.js"
});
```

nothing happens. In fact, even when the `contentScript.js` only contains `console.log('test')`, it doesn't seem to get processed by `webpack` in the way I imagine, since executing the script in the browser console doesn't yield anything.

What am I overseeing here? From `vue inspect` I can see the following `webpack`-rule for `js`:

```js
/* config.module.rule('js') */
      {
        test: /\.m?jsx?$/,
        exclude: [
          function () { /* omitted long function */ }
        ],
        use: [
          {
            loader: '/home/user/Coding/webext/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: '/home/user/Coding/webext/node_modules/.cache/babel-loader',
              cacheIdentifier: '356420a0'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: '/home/user/Coding/webext/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js'
          }
        ]
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! It's because of `splitChunks`  bundling all `node_module`  assets in a `vendor`-chunk. Since my `contentScript.js`-script didn't load this `vendor`-chunk, `webpack` couldn't do its thing. That seems to be the case because `webpack`  itself requires some ES-`node_modules`. Would've been really helpful if `webpack` had let me know that it was missing a chunk, but oh well...The necessary configuration in the `vue.config.js` is:

```js
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.optimization.splitChunks(false);
  }
```